# Pytest error in teardown when using logging

Tags: python, logging, pytest

When I run my test if I cancel it using ctrl-c (keyboard interrupt) after it has yielded, it should continue running the code after the yield statement. However if I run it with logging enabled:

```
pytest test_logging_error.py --log-cli-level info
```

It causes an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'resume_capturing'
```

It does this after it logs the message "It crashes here", here is the code.

```
from time import sleep
import pytest
import logging


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def connection():
    numbers = []
    for i in range(10):
        numbers.append(i)
    yield numbers
    logging.info("It crashes here")
    for i in range(10):
        print("foo")


def test_error(connection):
    logging.info("Running a test")
    sleep(10000)
```

If I run it without logging after the yield or just with logging disabled it runs fine and the teardown finishes properly.

Comment: so are you cancelling your tests or not?

Comment: Yes I am cancelling them when they are running

Comment: so you are terminating your tests and want to see tests running?

Comment: I want to see logging during the teardown however the logging is causing the teardown to fail

Comment: It should print foo 10 times but at the moment it logs "It crashes here" then crashes but only if I cancel it, if I let it run for 10000s then it tears down as expected

Comment: I think it could be a bug in pytest. Try with an older version like `pip install pytest<3.9.0`

Comment: Looks like it is a pytest bug, I tried it with pip install 'pytest<3.9.0' and it worked.

Comment: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an actual pytest bug, i believe https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/4487 fixes it (its just been merged into master)

but thanks to the bug report made in https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4500 we now have a minimal reproducer for that issue which cna be added as a regression test

for additional clairty please verify with pytest from master if the issue is resolved, i'll follow up with adding the test to the testsuite when i find time

thanks :+1: